# how to switch component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I would like to let users to move main component after they create content and I don't what methods I need to use. I wanted to use something like history but it didn't work. I am using

- "react": "^17.0.2",
- "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
- "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class CreateContent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      content: {
        title: ''
      }
    }
  }

  handleInput = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      content : {
        ...this.state.content,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
    })
  }

  addContent = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.title))
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:9000/api/v1/content', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state.content),
        mode:'cors',
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });

      if(!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText)
      }
// ******* HERE I wanted to add something like *******
      history.push('/main')
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('addContent failed -', err)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.addContent}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="title"
            onChange={this.handleInput}
            value={this.state.content.title}
          />
          <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CreateContent
```

Comment: You need to use `React Router`.  If I understood correctly, you want to user to navigate to some custom link if so use `<Link to="/detail">Go To Details</Link>`

Similarly, you would have some link from the detail page to come back to the `main` page.

Comment: @ParagDiwan I wanted to use it inside of the function so that I can let users to move main page after they succeed POST request. I used to use history.push but I guess it is not working anymore..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `React Router v6`, you need to use **useNavigate** instead of **history.push()**.

But, since you're using **class component** [`React Router v6` it doesn't support these hooks out of the box for the class components](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it). That is why you are receiving the error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

But that doesn't mean you can't use it. You can recreate it using HOC:

```
import {
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

function withRouter(Component) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props) {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        router={{ location, navigate, params }}
      />
    );
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}
```

You can now wrap and export your class-based components to `withRouter` HOC in the very familiar way they were from v4/v5.

After that you can use `useNavigate` from `react-router-dom v6`.

```
const navigate = useNavigate()
navigate("/main")
```

Regarding your query that you've mentioned in the comment:

> So should I create a separate component to add the above code or I should add the above code for each component that I want to use history? or should I add it into App.js?

To work around this issue first, create a new component `withRouter`  as indicated above, and then wrap `CreateContent` component in a `withRouter` function, when it is exported:

```
export default withRouter(CreateContent)
```

`withRouter` will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

`withRouter` reference in v5: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I think your answer is what I am looking for and tried to apply it to my app but I am not quietly how to use it.  So should I create seperate component to add the above code or I should add above code each component that I want to use history? or shoud I add it into App.js? Could you please add example? Thank you!

Comment: I created withRouter.js file in top level(src)and copy and pasted your code. And wonder how to import that in CreateContent.js? I added `export default withRouter` in withRouter.js and `import {withRouter} from './withRouter'` and I still wrong? Thank you again!

Comment: Are you still facing issue or it's resolved? @Cindy

Comment: Thank you for follow up with me! I was able to make it! It was really great solution @Sanket Shah !

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve redirection in multiple ways in react.

1- just use Link from react-router-dom

```
<Link to={"/my-route"} />
```

2- you can use useNavigate from react-router-dom

```
const navigate = useNavigate()
navigate("/my-route")
```

3- you can simple use state to show/hide compoenents if

```
const [visibleComponent, setVisibleComponent] = useState('component1')
<Component1 isVisible={visibleComponent === 'component1'} />
<Component2 isVisible={visibleComponent === 'component2'} />
<Component3 isVisible={visibleComponent === 'component3'} />
```

and then you can change the component based on your logic ( setVisibleComponent('component2') to show the second component and so on ...

Comment: so.. I want to use it inside of function like my example. Once you hit the button, you will post your content and then let users to move to main page. I tried 2. but it returns `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:` because   I am using class component(I think..)

Comment: yes you cannot use hooks in class based components, what you can do is to create a button component, make it functionnal component so you can use hooks and then use inside it the useNavigate()